# SmoothPageIndicator work with CarouselSlider Flutter

Tags: flutter

before SmoothPageIndicator works fine with CarouselSlider since it just needs an activeIndex, but the current version of SmoothPageIndicator need a Pagecontroller, and what I have is a CarouselController, how could I transfer this CarouselController to a pagecontroller?

```
SmoothPageIndicator(
              controller: _pageController // here I only have a CarouselController
              count: controller.photoFrameList.length + 1,
              effect: WormEffect(
                activeDotColor: AppColors.sadColor,
                dotColor: AppColors.sadColor.withOpacity(0.4),
                dotHeight: 8,
                dotWidth: 8,
                type: WormType.thin,
                // strokeWidth: 5,
              ),
            ),
```

thank you!

Comment: You can't, I just inspected the carousel slider code.
You cannot do it.

Comment: Hi Denzel, thanks for the comment, I checked the changelog, the writer create another api at [0.2.0] AnimatedSmoothIndicator which does not need PageController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the PageController by extending the CarouselController.

```
class CustomCarouselController extends CarouselControllerImpl {
  CarouselState? _state;
  CarouselState? get state => _state;

  @override
  set state(CarouselState? state) {
    _state = state;
    super.state = state;
  }
}
```

Then use it after making sure it's ready to be accessed

```
        FutureBuilder(
          future: _carouselController.onReady,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: SmoothPageIndicator(
                    controller: _carouselController.state!.pageController!,
                    count: _carouselController.state!.itemCount!,
                    onDotClicked: (val) {
                      _carouselController.animateToPage(val - 1);
                    },
                    effect: SlideEffect(
                      activeDotColor: AppData.color,
                      paintStyle: PaintingStyle.stroke,
                      spacing: 10,
                      dotWidth: 20,
                      dotColor: Colors.white,
                      strokeWidth: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the changelog, the writer create another api at [0.2.0] AnimatedSmoothIndicator which does not need PageController